# php I am printing a number that is displaying as -0

Tags: php, negative-number

In php I am displaying a number that I am making red if it is negative and green otherwise:

```
if ($daysAhead>=0) $class = "ahead";
else $class = "behind";
echo "<span class=\"$class\">$daysAhead</span>";
```

I have a number that is displaying as green and it prints as `-0`.

Why is it displaying the negative sign?  Why is -0>=0 evaluating as true?

Comment: what are the possible values of `$daysAhead` in your case

Comment: rounded floating point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a webpage that discusses the concept of negative zero:

http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2008/12/negative-zero-what-is-it.html
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920_(number)

Turns out I was rounding the number to the nearest decimal.  so `.009` was rounding to `.0` but it was also negative.

It also turns out in php `floatval(-0.0)==0`.

This prompted me to write some very peculiar code:

```
if ($daysAhead==0){  
    $daysAhead=0;
}
if ($daysAhead>=0) $class = "ahead";
else $class = "behind";
```

Comment: I think this should be a part of your question.